# Getting a GameObject from Plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango, plane, gameobject

I'd like to know if there's an easy way to represent a Plane as a GameObject.

I'm using the FindPlane method from Tango's PointCloud that returns a Plane and I'd like to create a GameObject from that Plane so I can see it in my 3d world.

Thx :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the API only returns the [Unity Plane](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html) data structure, that data structure doesn't have a game object associated with it.

In order to create the game object at the plane's location, you will need to instantiate the game object programmatically like this:

```
// Tango Find Plane function in the TangoPrefabs/Scripts/TangoPointCloud.cs
FindPlane(cam, pos, maxPixelDist, minInlierPercentage, ref planeCenter, ref Plane plane);
Instantiate(targetGameobject, planeCenter, Quaternion.identity);
```

Comment: Maybe you could include rotating the plane, i.e. `LookAt` the plane's normal.